# Undefined variable? Maybe the query is wrong?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to apply filters to my products

This is my database

[image]

I'm trying to filter by gender, if it is a kid or not, price range and size

My form:

```
<form method="GET" action="{{route('products.all')}}">
    <div class="filters">
        <select class="form-control search" name="gender">
            <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Gender...</option>
            <option value="M">Man</option>
            <option value="W">Woman</option>
        </select>
        
        <label>Kids?</label>
        <input class="form-control search" type="checkbox" name="kids" value="1">

        <div class="filters-all">
            Price...
            <div class="search">
                <input type="text" class="start d-none" name="price-start" />
                <input type="text" class="end d-none" name="price-end" />
                <input type="text" id="sampleSlider" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <select class="form-control search" name="size">
            <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Sizes...</option>
            @foreach($sizes as $size)
            <option value="{{$size->size}}">{{$size->size}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>

        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary"value="Filter"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

My controller with query:

```
$gender = $request->get('gender');
        $child = $request->get('kids');
        $size = $request->get('size');
        $price_start = $request->input('price-start');
        $price_end = $request->input('price-end');
        
        if(!empty($gender) && !empty($size)&& !empty($price_start) && !empty($price_end)){
           Product::whereHas('stocks', function ($query) {
                    $query->where('size', '=', $size);
                })
                ->whereHas('childs', function ($query){
                    $query->where('child', '=', $child);
                })
                ->where('gender', '=', $gender)
                ->whereBetween('price', [$price_start, $price_end])
                ->inRandomOrder()->paginate(12);
        }else{
              $products = Product::inRandomOrder()->paginate(12);
        }
```

When submitting the form data, it appears correctly in the get:

[image]

But when filtering, the link returns "that the variables are not initialized"

[image]

I've been thinking for a while but I have the solution. Maybe the query is wrong?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php  example #3

Comment: wow, I was so sure that what was failing was the query that I completely forgot the 'use', thank you very much!